# “Diabling IRQ #9” error at boot in manjaro linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, manjaro, irq

Whenever i start my pc. I see this error "Disabling IRQ #9". I only have manjaro on my pc (no dual boot) and wanted to know the cause behind this problem. Sudo systemctl returns no error but when i run journalctl i get this output knowing that i completely wiped my hard disk and reset my bios settings to the defaults before installing manjaro and i got the error the first time i started the fresh install. Output of "sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb"

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-11-15 12:28:58 CET, end at Sun 2020-11-15 12:45:20 CET. --
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dswload2-326)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dswload2-326)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C2.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C3.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ON], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dswload2-326)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dswload2-326)
Nov 15 12:31:30 aminbh kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
Nov 15 12:31:37 aminbh kernel: irq 9: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Nov 15 12:31:37 aminbh kernel: handlers:
Nov 15 12:31:37 aminbh kernel: [<000000005a66a59d>] acpi_irq
Nov 15 12:31:37 aminbh kernel: Disabling IRQ #9
Nov 15 12:31:44 aminbh wpa_supplicant[835]: nl80211: kernel reports: Attribute failed policy validation
Nov 15 12:31:44 aminbh wpa_supplicant[835]: Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3: -22 (Invalid argument)
Nov 15 12:31:44 aminbh wpa_supplicant[835]: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
Nov 15 12:31:46 aminbh kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: intr 00000040
Nov 15 12:32:52 aminbh bluetoothd[767]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error "attribute failed policy validation" during a avahi-autoipd init.  it uses a script that takes the nic name a tacks :avahi on the back. nic names have max length of 15 chars. you also hit this limit.
I believe you can change it with a kernel parameter and a reboot if you can't fix the code.
15 char limit applies to nic labels too.